# Command not found error when executing maven deploy via groovy

Tags: bash, maven, groovy

I have the following command I execute via groovy:

```
def mavenCommand        = "/opt/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn";
def mavenUrl            = "-Durl=${nexusUrl}";
def mavenRepoId         = "-DrepositoryId=${nexusRepo}";
def mavenGroupId        = "-DgroupId=${groupId}";
def mavenArtefactId = "-DartifactId=${artefactName}";
def mavenVersion    = "-Dversion=${artefactVersion}";
def mavenFile       = "-Dfile=${fileLocation}";
def mavenPackaging  = "-Dpackaging=${artefactExtension}";


uploadToNexus("${mavenCommand} deploy:deploy-file ${mavenUrl} ${mavenRepoId} ${mavenGroupId} ${mavenArtefactId} ${mavenVersion} ${mavenFile} ${mavenPackaging}");

public String uploadToNexus(command){
    def uploadToNexusProc = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c","${command}").redirectErrorStream(true).start();
    uploadToNexusProc.waitFor();
    println uploadToNexusProc.text;
    return uploadToNexusProc.exitValue();
}
```

Although in this instance it uploads to nexus successfully,It seems that the final argument is always missed resulting in:

```
-Dpackaging=zip : command not found
```

I understand that this is a shell error and for some reason `${mavenPackaging}` expands to a new line.
Can someone help me understand the cause of this problem? Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

${mavenPackaging"} was an error on my part when I was formatting the code on Stackoverflow. It was set correctly in my code. Now updated.

**EDIT 2**

If I were to do:

```
println "${mavenCommand} deploy:deploy-file ${mavenUrl} ${mavenRepoId} ${mavenGroupId} ${mavenArtefactId} ${mavenVersion} ${mavenFile} ${mavenPackaging}";
```

I get the following output (which highlights the problem):

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=http://server/content/repositories/releases -DrepositoryId=nexus -DgroupId=bogus.fake.fakeagain -DartifactId=api -Dversion=1.4.5 -Dfile=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp/api-1.4.5.zip
 -Dpackaging=zip
```

Comment: I think you want the quotes for `${mavenPackaging"}` outside the bracket, like so `${mavenPackaging}"` toward the end of the uploadToNexus line.

Comment: is there a reason you bring the shell here into the equation?  have you tried `new ProcessBuilder(mavenCommand, mavenUrl, mavenRepoId, mavenGroupId, mavenArtefactId, mavenVersion, mavenFile, mavenPackaging)...`

Comment: Oh and can you check, if your `fileLocation` ends in a linebreak?

Comment: Agree with zerodiff. The issue is that your " character is not at the correct place. put it after } ... i.e. ${mavenPackaging}");  instead of ${mavenPackaging"});

Comment: @cfrick: The `fileLocation` variable has no line breaks plus I previously had that argument at the end which resulted in the `mavenPackaging` argument to be read but not the `mavenFile` argument so its the last argument regardless of what it is by the looks of things.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line:

```
uploadToNexus("${mavenCommand} deploy:deploy-file ${mavenUrl} ${mavenRepoId} ${mavenGroupId} ${mavenArtefactId} ${mavenVersion} ${mavenFile} ${mavenPackaging"})
```

with

```
uploadToNexus("${mavenCommand} deploy:deploy-file ${mavenUrl} ${mavenRepoId} ${mavenGroupId} ${mavenArtefactId} ${mavenVersion} ${mavenFile} ${mavenPackaging}")
```

Comment: I agree, semicolon is optional at the end of line